# Joomla base URL incorrectly formulated

Tags: url, joomla, radix

Somehow my Joomla after an upgrade from 3.4.7 to 3.4.8 is not formulating the base URL properly. The base is supposed to be "www.domain.com/en-us/" for the English version of the site. It renders the following as the base url "www.domain.comhttp://www.domain.com/en-us/www.domain.com/"
further rendering the following url for resources, such as for "green_leaf.png": "www.domain.comhttp://www.domain.com/en-us/www.domain.com/images/green_leaf.png". Consequently, the pages full missing page elements.

SEF is enabled. Multi Language Filter Plugin is enabled. Any ideas what could be the cause of this besides, the configuration and the htaccess files? Those file are pretty standard.

Comment: It looks like something like a plugin is modifying the base url and it's been added without http:// Check your system plugins or template frameworks to see if they have an option. Also, enable the admin multilanguage module which will let you know if everything is set up correctly. If these urls all come from an extension then the issue is probably with that extension.

Answer (score 0):

The first things I would confirm are
- in **system > global configuration > site** -- is URL rewriting set to yes and have you renamed htaccess to .htaccess?
- if yes then ftp to your site, open configuration.php in a text editor, locate the line setting the $live_site variable and change to
public $live_site = 'http://www.domain.com';

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your suggestion, to specify the $live_site variable in the configuration.php file as you indicate, even though I have also been recommended to leave it empty. The results were the same, the issue remains.

Here is the latest on this matter:
I have created a local copy of the site on my machine from a backup that was still Joomla 3.4.7. The same issue appears. I have reverted back to an earlier backup with Joomla 3.4.6 version of the site, and the site's page was restored to normal. This is with the same exact .htaccess and configuration.php across the 3 Joomla versions.

I have also tried with "Options +FollowSymLinks" commented out in the .htaccess file that came with J3.4.8. On both the live hosted site and a locally hosted copy, same exact results, namely:
Using Google Chrome (with Language Filter Enabled and set to Remove URL Language Code)
On the live hosted site: 
www.domain . comhttp://www.domain.com/www.domain.com/ 
On the localhost copy of the site: localhost/domainfolder/localhost/domainfolder/http://localhost/domainfolder/localhost/domainfolder/domainfolder

So this issue might be pertaining to Joomla versions 3.4.7 and 3.4.8. The challenge is that 3.4.6 also has critical security vulnerabilities.

Also tried with Language Filter Disabled - Same result (Base URL formulated as above) with the difference that all the languages are displayed at the same time on the home page with the resources that are not found because of the faulty base url.

Comment: You shouldn't update your own question by adding an answer which doesn't fix the original issue. I just wasted time by replying to your original issue. You should remove the livesite variable, it should not contain the language code (unless your site is actually in a folder called en-us/)